# ruby httparty for perl?

Tags: perl, api, http

does exists anything in perl similar to http://httparty.rubyforge.org/ ?
other libraries to deal with http api?

greets

Comment: Can you briefly describe what httparty is?

Answer (score 3):

The canonical packages for interacting with websites are [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize), [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aUserAgent) and [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aSimple). I think Mechanize would do what you are looking for quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

I think HTTParty looks very similar to Perl's [WebService::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WebService%3a%3aSimple).

Answer (score 1):

Does [HTTP::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/HTTP-Lite-2.3/lib/HTTP/Lite.pm) help? (I don't know what the ruby httparty does).